# Как настроить SSL сертификат для виртуального хоста по умолчанию в CentOS?

Tags: apache, ssl, virtual-hosts

В системе Centos 7 используется Apache 2.4 и настроено использование SSL сертификатов. Все работает нормально, но недавно заметил, что если выбрать домен, для которого нет SSL, то показывается последний сайт из тех, кто имеет такой сертификат.

И в общем-то было бы пофиг на это, но почему-то гугл начал индексировать такие сайты, хотя ссылок на них нет и никто ему не давал повода.

Я заметил что не было создано виртуального хоста по умолчанию для 443 порта. Я его создал, но вот теперь вопрос - как для него создать сертификат? Для сертификата же надо указать имя сайта, а здесь его нет.
Я так полагаю что надо выпускать самоподписанный, но даже самоподписанный должен иметь адрес....

Как быть? Как вообще правильно разруливается эта ситуация? В интернете много написано про домены по умолчанию, но только не для SSL.

Тайна....

временно конфигурация хоста по умолчанию сейчас такая:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName default
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/000-default
<Directory /var/www/html/000-default>
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ServerSignature Off
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/000-default-error-log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/000-default-access-log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName default
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/000-default
<Directory /var/www/html/000-default>
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ServerSignature Off
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/beef-on-error-log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/beef-on-access-log vhost_combined
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.beef-on.ru/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.beef-on.ru/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.beef-on.ru/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Пока что используются ключи от другого сайта.

Comment: Я бы сделал так, чтобы все подключения на виртуальный хост по умолчанию просто отклонялись. В nginx это делается через return 444, а как в апаче не в курсе

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать специальный виртуальный домен (например ip-адрес), для него выпустить сертификат и сделать редирект с дефолтного домена на этот.

Comment: а насколько это все правильно? Насколько является рекомендуемым? И разве можно делать виртуальный домен для IP адреса? и как это будет работать  и выглядеть?

Comment: @progreccor Это вообще неправильно, так как сам принцип создания удостоверяющих сертификатов, чем является SSL-сертификат, предполагает его владельца, а вот дефолтный домен, это домен, сделанный для того случая, когда ни один конкретный домен на данном сервере не найден, а нужно что-то показать.

Comment: и что же делать? Гугл постоянно пытается проверить https всех сайтов которые есть.